# How do I determine the cause of this JVM crash?

Tags: jvm, jodatime, freebsd, java

I'm getting a JVM crash which seems to be caused by a Joda Time method but I'm not really sure where to go from here, how do I go about determining the root cause?

Full error report here:
http://pastie.org/8497632

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000803a6a520, pid=83287, tid=39552004096
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b15
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J  org.joda.time.chrono.BasicChronology.getYearMillis(I)J
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/core or core.83287
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Core dump shows:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000800cbfbfc in thr_kill () from /lib/libc.so.7
#1  0x0000000800d63dab in abort () from /lib/libc.so.7
#2  0x0000000801b8d829 in os::abort (dump_core=true)
    at /var/ports/basejail/usr/ports/java/openjdk7/work/openjdk/hotspot/src/os/bsd/vm/os_bsd.cpp:1786
#3  0x0000000801ce5ea1 in VMError::report_and_die (this=0x7ffffc9e1550)
    at /var/ports/basejail/usr/ports/java/openjdk7/work/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/vmError.cpp:1010
#4  0x0000000801b9109b in JVM_handle_bsd_signal (sig=11, info=0x7ffffc9e1db0, ucVoid=0x7ffffc9e1a40, abort_if_unrecognized=1)
    at /var/ports/basejail/usr/ports/java/openjdk7/work/openjdk/hotspot/src/os_cpu/bsd_x86/vm/os_bsd_x86.cpp:748
#5  0x0000000800a470ce in pthread_sigmask () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#6  0x0000000800a4725c in pthread_sigmask () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#7  0x00007ffffffff193 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000800a47180 in pthread_sigmask () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: check the core dump file, there might be some indication their. but SIGSEGV  indicates that its a segmentation fault.

Comment: What version of joda time are you using?

Comment: Joda-Time version 2.3